# ERROR: "token" parameter not in video info in youtube-dl

Tags: updates, youtube-dl

This error occurred when using youtube-dl:

```
[youtube] 1234567890A: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 1234567890A: Downloading video info webpage
ERROR: 1234567890A: "token" parameter not in video info for unknown reason;   
please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug. 
Make sure you are using the latest version; type youtube-dl -U to update.   
Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

I tried to uninstall youtube-dl and reinstall it, but this error reoccurred.

Comment: @karel I'm fairly sure that's not the issue here. To me it seems that the -U command is recognized, but disabled in the latest Ubuntu Version(s).

Comment: CLOSE VOTERS: Note the answer below which answers the question quite directly and gives details of the Debian changes leading to this unexpected behaviour from youtube-dl...

Comment: I'd much rather see both posts merged to a "how do I keep this updated?" question

Comment: @muru Perhaps: 'How to keep youtube-dl updated under Ubuntu 18.04?' I would be happy to create a 'Question and Answer' question and merge both questions. Incorporating: 1. The issue with the Debian patching 2. The method to update using wget 3. The method to update using pip. Then mark both existing questions as dupes?

Comment: @andrew.46 "how do I keep YouTube-dl updated" period; your answer describing 1,2; karel's merged in (or the other way around - merge your answer here to the dupe).

Comment: @muru OK, done. I tend to tweak my answers over a short period so there will be improvements coming...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update youtube-dl to the latest version.

```
sudo youtube-dl -U # no longer supported in Debian-based systems
```

If youtube-dl cannot be updated with this command, install the latest version of youtube-dl using Alternative Python package installer (pip).

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
sudo apt-get install python-pip  
pip install --user youtube-dl
```

In Ubuntu 14.04 and later youtube-dl is a snap package. To install it:

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl
```

The youtube-dl snap package will be updated automatically in the background when updates become available.

Comment: I tried it for many videos but the result is same.. I even tried to download videos using "all video downloader" but it is also not working...

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 you can use the command: `youtube-dl -F 'http://www.youtube.com/some-alphanumeric-string'` to display a list of all the video formats that are available for any YouTube video that you want to download. For example `-f 35` is the option to use to download the common 360p flv video format. For more information about the most commonly used options for youtube-dl see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334081/youtube-dl-multiple-files-downloading/334097#334097).

Comment: Result is same as previous.. Same error..

Comment: For an experiment try downloading the following 5-second YouTube video using this command: `youtube-dl -f 18 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBPPLu2x3lI` This video is in the 480p mp4 format, and downloading it will help to test if you have a problem downloading only flv format videos.

Comment: Same tokan error for above URL

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Can you watch the video in a web browser?

Comment: Yes I can watch it..

Answer (score 4):

**Keeping youtube-dl updated:**

`youtube-dl` is an application that is updated every couple of weeks to match changes made by upstream services such as YouTube. Consequently keeping it update is *a busy task*. As of Ubuntu 18.04 there is a special issue where the Ubuntu package can no longer be 'manually' updated. Thus the command `youtube-dl -U` does not work with the repository version of `youtube-dl`.

**Recent Issues with the Ubuntu package:**

The Debian package managers for youtube-dl have felt that it "contains a (possibly-insecure) self-update mechanism" and have patched this auto-update mechanism completely *out of the application*. The bug report and discussion are here:

Debian Bug report logs - #890119 
[youtube-dl contains a (possibly-insecure) self-update mechanism](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890119)

The patch to youtube-dl is *quite extensive* and arguably a little destructive. It can be seen in full [here...](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890119) Note the comment at the top of the patch:

> Knowledgeable users will know what to do in any case.

And the good news is that are 2 very good methods for 'knowledgeable users' to keep `youtube-dl` updated:

**1. Update using wget:**

And for my own part that involves the following simple commands which *remove* the repository youtube-dl and manually install *the most recent version*:

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
sudo mkdir -pv /usr/local/bin
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

And now youtube-dl will function as before :). Bear in mind that you will need to periodically *manually* update youtube-dl (by running `youtube-dl -U`) rather than expect the package manager to do it for you...

**2. Updating using the pip installer:**

You can instead use the Alternative Python package installer (pip) to update `youtube-dl` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
sudo apt-get install python-pip  
sudo pip install youtube-dl
```

Then subsequently you can *update* `youtube-dl` by running the following:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```

And now enjoy your *offline* viewing of YouTube's great video offerings :).

Comment: youtube-dl: as you know the normal upgrade command is not working e.g. `youtube-dl -U` Thus having to remove and re-install using pip (not sure why) has been a common workaround.  As a side effect I have noticed that when verifying the version directly after install I get a return: `Bash: /usr/bin/youtube-dl: file not found.` Then I find the file actually in `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` Once a reboot has occurred the file is in `/usr/bin/youtube-dl`
Q: why is this? And what if any info can you share explaining the change of location after reboot. Perhaps add this to your answer as well. thanks