# How do I keep youtube-dl updated?

Tags: software-installation, youtube-dl

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. I used to update youtube-dl via `youtube-dl -U`, but now I get the error:

```
youtube-dl: error: youtube-dl's self-update mechanism is disabled on Debian. 
Please update youtube-dl using apt.
```

So will I always get the recent (stable!!) update by going

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

as for everything else, or will I have to add a new repository?

Comment: @MarkusGratis `sudo youtube-dl -U # no longer supported in Debian-based systems` - [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486576/error-token-parameter-not-in-video-info-in-youtube-dl/486590#486590) which is practically the same thing as what you said in your comment with minor changes in the wording, that the `-U` option of `youtube-dl` is currently disabled.

Comment: @andrew.46 ah, when I said "merged" I meant the merging described in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled