# Cannot download youtube-dl

Tags: updates, youtube-dl

I was trying to download a video from YouTube using youtube-dl, but I got the sig error, so I tried to update youtube-dl to the latest version and it wasn't working. I'm sorry, I don't remember what the error was or what it said in the terminal when I tried to update. So I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling youtube-dl. The uninstalling part worked fine, it's the installing part that I need help with now.

I tried typing `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` and I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
youtube-dl is already the newest version.  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

So, I assumed that that meant that I had it installed, but when I tried to use it, nothing happens, or rather I just get this:

```
root@chaaaaaaarlie3:~# youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eISomx-VMow
root@chaaaaaaarlie3:~#
```

and the video obviously doesn't download.

I have been trying to fix this problem for a while now and I have no idea what to do. I also have almost no knowledge of how to use terminals/Ubuntu/computers/things of that sort, so if you could be very specific when helping me, I'd appreciate it. (Okay, I'm not COMPLETELY stupid, but I really don't know much. Let's just say that youtube-dl is the ONLY thing that I use the terminal for >.> )

I'm not sure if this would be what's messing up my attempts to use youtube-dl, but I think I uninstalled youtube-dl and it's dependencies and I may have purged my local/config files for youtube-dl too. I can't really remember all that I did last night when I was trying to fix this...

Comment: I got the same error when I tried to download that video so I think there might be a problem with downloading that particular video. To test if youtube-dl is working try downloading this 5-second video: `youtube-dl -f 18 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBPPLu2x3lI`. For an explanation of the most commonly used commands for youtube-dl see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334081/youtube-dl-multiple-files-downloading/334097#334097

Comment: Unfortunately, Youtube-dl isn't downloading ANYTHING anymore, not just that video.

Comment: Try updating youtube-dl to that latest version by running the command: `sudo youtube-dl -U` and then try to download the 5-second video in the link in the previous comment again.

Comment: I have tried updating it, and nothing happens. It's supposed to say something after you type "sudo youtube-dl -U" and then hit enter, right? For me, it just does what it did when I tried downloading the video. And, I tried again just to see if anything would happen, and still nothing happened when I tried to download that 5 second video :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Ubuntu 12.10 which is an End of Life release. I know this from your terminal output about `Setting up 2014.06.02-1~webupd8~quantal` from this PPA: ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 which is found at [this webpage](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+index?field.series_filter=&batch=75&direction=backwards&start=300). That's why you can't update youtube-dl. Your version of youtube-dl is out of date and Google has changed the code required to download a YouTube video since Ubuntu 12.10 was released. That is why you can't download any video. Try installing the latest version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 14.04, which is a Long Term Support release that is supported by updates until April, 2019, and youtube-dl will work the way it's supposed to.

Then try to download a 5-second test video to check if youtube-dl is working:

```
youtube-dl -f 18 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBPPLu2x3lI
```

If that doesn't work the apt version of YouTube is not up-to-date, so install the *youtube-dl* snap package instead:

```
sudo apt install snapd  
sudo snap install youtube-dl # start with snap run youtube-dl
```

Comment: Oh, alright then. I'll have to wait until the next time I see my brother-in-law to update my OS, because he's my computer expert and I know nothing about how to update my OS myself.... (Yes, I really am THAT stupid when it comes to computers)
But thank you for your help!! :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to upgrade the system. Update `youtube-dl` by adding this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Then you may download any video as usual. For example:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ix1rD4JD3eo
```

Answer (score 4):

Possibly the easiest way to install and setup youtube-dl is to use the following [two commands suggested by the youtube-dl developers](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html):

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2015.04.09/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

And to subsequently update youtube-dl simply run the following:

```
sudo youtube-dl --update
```

Best to update at regular intervals as youtube-dl is updated often to match changes at the You Tube end...