# How to download all videos of 1 account on Instagram

Tags: video, downloads, youtube, source-code, youtube-dl

In the past I used to use youtube-dl to download all videos of an instagram channel but today I use that channel again and it doesn't work.

```
youtube-dl -i -f mp4 -o %(uploader_id)s-%(id)s.mp4 -a 1.txt
```

Now how can I use youtube-dl to download the whole video

Comment: Perhaps try yt-dlp? Latest version is 2022.10.04 while youtube-dl has not been updated since 2021.12.17. Usage should be the same...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot download youtube-dl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487363/cannot-download-youtube-dl) (accepted answer)