# How can I use youtube-dl to download playlist with all videos in the formats of 360P?

Tags: 14.04, youtube, youtube-dl

I had known how to choose formats for a single video.But if I'd like to download a playlist with all videos in the formats of 360P,how can I do ?Thanks!

Comment: You can use the same options as with downloading just one file (i.e. -f18) - format codes are fixed. Since if a video is not available in this format will result in stopping download you'll, most likely, want to add the option -i to ignore errors.

Comment: @adonis That works! All the videos have the same format code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [youtube-dl multiple files downloading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334081/youtube-dl-multiple-files-downloading)

Answer (score 2):

First check for the format code of the video quality you want:

```
$ youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSXu8_7Y8pIb7BraT3mpyCBDk7RQ2QZlb
```

This command gives you:

```
format code  extension  resolution note
139          m4a        audio only DASH audio   48k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.5@ 48k (22050Hz)
249          webm       audio only DASH audio   50k , opus @ 50k, 762.50KiB
250          webm       audio only DASH audio   59k , opus @ 70k, 866.37KiB
171          webm       audio only DASH audio   90k , vorbis@128k, 1.28MiB
251          webm       audio only DASH audio  108k , opus @160k, 1.53MiB
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  127k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k (44100Hz)
160          mp4        256x144    DASH video   77k , avc1.4d400c, 30fps, video only
278          webm       256x144    144p   99k , webm container, vp9, 30fps, video only, 968.10KiB
242          webm       426x240    240p  172k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 1.44MiB
133          mp4        426x240    DASH video  192k , avc1.4d4015, 30fps, video only
134          mp4        640x360    DASH video  306k , avc1.4d401e, 30fps, video only
243          webm       640x360    360p  361k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 2.78MiB
244          webm       854x480    480p  618k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 4.66MiB
135          mp4        854x480    DASH video  720k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only
247          webm       1280x720   720p 1362k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 9.98MiB
136          mp4        1280x720   DASH video 1446k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only
17           3gp        176x144    small , mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2@ 24k
36           3gp        320x180    small , mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2
43           webm       640x360    medium , vp8.0, vorbis@128k
18           mp4        640x360    medium , avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2@ 96k
22           mp4        1280x720   hd720 , avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2@192k (best)
```

So, from here, we know that 360p format code is 18

Now, to download whole playlist in this format, simply fire up:

```
$ youtube-dl -citf 18 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSXu8_7Y8pIb7BraT3mpyCBDk7RQ2QZlb
```