# How can I download a YouTube playlist?

Tags: 16.04, downloads, youtube

How can I download a YouTube playlist on Ubuntu?

I tried `youtube-dl` but it's long to change quality, edit crashed file and pause list.

I tried also `JDownloader` but it takes too much Memory, CPU and it's very slow while downloading.

Is there another method?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What do you mean by "edit crashed file and pause list"?  It'd help if you edited your question to expand on that a bit, so that we can understand your requirements or what criteria a good solution must meet.

Comment: @D.W. if youtube-dl cannot download a single video file in a playlist (for example because the video does not allow embedding or whatever other trick youtube-dl uses) then it crashes without downloading the rest of the videos. To workaround this you must manually get a list of the videos in the playlist and supply this to youtube-dl, then every time it fails to download a video and crashes you have to edit your list, remove that video, delete the partially downloaded junk files it created and restart it.

Comment: @AlistairBuxton, thanks!  Mind adding that to the question?  Rather than putting elaborations in the comments, it's often better to suggest an edit to the question to add this information to the question itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading multiple files with youtube-dl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334081/downloading-multiple-files-with-youtube-dl)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try [Youtube Multi downloader](http://youtubemultidownloader.com/index.html). It's super easy to control quality, but you will need to install downloader support Batch downloads. I use [UGet](http://ugetdm.com/). It's simple and supports queue download.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need another program -- you can actually solve your problems, using `youtube-dl`.  Use

```
youtube-dl -i ..playlist..
```

The `-i` flag will cause youtube-dl to continue if it encounters any errors.  If one video in the playlist can't be downloaded, it'll skip that video and continue on to the next, thanks to the `-i` flag.

There is no need to specify any command-line options to specify the quality.  The defaults are reasonable: the default is to download the highest-quality video and audio available, which probably makes sense in most cases.

If you don't like specifying flags on the command line, you can put them in youtube-dl's configuration file (e.g., `~/.config/youtube-dl/config`).

It's amazing what you can find when you read the manual page!

Comment: youtube-dl --format mp4 --playlist-random   https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWF0RicJb20da8nECQ1jFvla

Comment: @ManikandanArunachalam, I'm afraid the comments here aren't the place to troubleshoot your problem. You could try asking  a new question (use the 'Ask Question' button in the upper-right), but you'll need to include more information in the question to help people help you.

Answer (score 4):

I use `youtube-dl` + `Youtube-dl GUI`, you can Install the two of them as follows :

#### 1. Install `youtube-dl` :

By default, Youtube-dl is not available in the Ubuntu-16.04 repository. So you will need to download it from their official website. You can download it with the curl command, First, install curl with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install curl -y
```

Next, download the youtube-dl binary:

```
curl -L https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/bin/youtube-dl
```

Next, change the permission of the youtube-dl binary package with the following command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/youtube-dl
```

Now `youtube-dl` is installed.

#### 2. Install `Youtube-dl GUI` :

By default, this tool is not available in Ubuntu 16.04 repository. So you will need to add PPA for that.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

Next, update your package repository and install youtube-dlg with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install youtube-dlg -y
```

Once Youtube-dl is installed, you can launch it from Unity Dashboard.

Source : [Install and Use YouTube-DL on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-and-use-youtube-dl-on-ubuntu-1604/)

Comment: in ubuntu, using `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` is usually a preferred option

Comment: Why use `curl` ? Isn't `wget` available?

Comment: GUI PPA not working in Ubuntu 20.10  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`

Answer (score 0):

You can install [savefrom](http://en.savefrom.net/1-how-to-download-youtube-video/) adds-ons in your browser, and it will give you the URLs from YouTube playlists.

Answer (score 0):

There's something similar for standard youtube-dl, but faster:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yt-dlp/stable    # Add ppa repo to apt
sudo apt update                              # Update package list
sudo apt install yt-dlp                      # Install yt-dlp
```

And, as D.W. suggested, but using yt-dlp:

```
yt-dlp -i https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbO86FG77std69waOv_othw3NgpCNn_7m
```