# Download videos from youtube playlist or user based on date

Tags: downloads, youtube, youtube-dl

Can I do a **date-wise download** of youtube videos of particular user or playlist using youtube-dl ?

For example - download all videos uploaded by User X in this week.

Looking for provision of downloading youtube videos from a channel/user/playlist with start-date and end-date.

Comment: No its not. Do not miss the "date-wise" part.

Comment: Downloading a date range with youtube-dl is a little bit more complicated, but there is an answer about that too in a different question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334081/youtube-dl-multiple-files-downloading/334097#334097 This answer is actually the way I usually do it myself, because I usually don't want to download some of the videos in a playlist, so I have to make a list of all the downloadable video links and then delete the links that I don't want.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, how do I remove that ?
Can I get the video info like date of upload before triggering download?

Comment: Alright, I get it that you want to scrape the videos' date data from the YouTube website automatically, so I retracted my "possible duplicate of...". There is a package for scraping website data in the default Ubuntu repositories, so it should be possible to do it automatically.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  From the youtube-dl man page:

```
--date DATE
          Download only videos uploaded in this date

--datebefore DATE
          Download only videos uploaded on or before this date (i.e.  inclusive)

--dateafter DATE
          Download only videos uploaded on or after this date (i.e.  inclusive)
```

Not stated there, but only hidden in the code, is that `DATE` is in the format `YYYYMMDD` or
    `(now|today)[+-][0-9](day|week|month|year)(s)?`, so for example the 17th August 2016 would be `20160817`, and seven days ago would be `now-7days` or `now-1week`.

You can specify a range by using `--datebefore` and `--dateafter` together, so:

```
youtube-dl -i --dateafter 20160808 --datebefore 20160810 https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL
```

will download all videos from a channel uploaded between and including August 8th and August 10th 2016, and:

```
youtube-dl -i --dateafter now-1week https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAYLIST
```

will download all videos from a playlist uploaded in the past week.

The `-i` option prevents `youtube-dl` from exiting prematurely if some videos are unavailable.

Note `youtube-dl` will still say it is downloading each video even when it doesn't. For example:

```
[download] Downloading video 1 of 123
[youtube] xxxxxxxxxxx: Downloading webpage
[youtube] xxxxxxxxxxx: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] xxxxxxxxxxx: Extracting video information
[youtube] xxxxxxxxxxx: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] 2016-08-07 upload date is not in range 2016-08-08 - 2016-08-10
[download] Downloading video 2 of 123
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your looking for this solution to sync a playlist or channel.

```
youtube-dl -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 --download-archive Filename.txt https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAYLIST
```