# How to download Videos from a YouTube playlist from past hour?

Tags: 16.04, youtube-dl

I am trying to figure out a way to download YouTube videos from a playlist using `youtube-dl` that were uploaded in the past hour - is there a way to do that?

Comment: You mean all the videos that where uploaded within the last hour, or a video that was uploaded maximum, an hour ago?

Comment: I assume older than 1 hour before censors erase some of them. But we are talking many Terabytes per hour and a data centre would be needed. Plus google would see the extraordinary volume and shut you down.

Comment: I mean if i put in a playlist link into youtube-dl it should reject all uploads that are older than one hour

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Just a few ballpark figures: from [YouTube Statistics](https://fortunelords.com/youtube-statistics/): _"300 hours of video are uploaded to YouTube every minute!"_ This gives 18,000 hours or approximately **2 years of non-stop video material every single hour**.

Answer (score 2):

The following command will download all the video on your subscription page uploaded in the past 24 hours:

```
youtube-dl \
  https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions \
  --dateafter now-1day \
  -u <username>
```

you'll have to change. See also: [Download videos from youtube playlist or user based on date](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811143/download-videos-from-youtube-playlist-or-user-based-on-date)